# Query results missing column names Prestodb via Python

Tags: python, pycharm, presto

I am fairly new to Python, and I am using prestodb to connect to a database to pull data and manipulate it. Everything works fine, except the query results do not have column names.

I saw a post about enabling headers in SQL+, but I am unable to find anything for prestodb. I checked the documentation on GitHub, but I am either not experienced enough or did not find a way to change the results for genall, fetchall, etc.

Does anyone have ideas on how to pull in column names/headers with my query?

Code:

```
conn = prestodb.dbapi.connect(
    host='hostname',
    port=4443,
    user='username',
    catalog='meld',
    schema='athena',
    http_scheme='https',
    auth=prestodb.auth.BasicAuthentication("username", "password"),
)

cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute('SELECT * FROM meld.athena.athena_business_summary limit 10')
query = cur.genall()
rows = pd.DataFrame(query)
print(rows)
```

[Query Results:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4JvKF.png)

Answer (score 2):

You can get column names from `cur.description`.

Comment: Will that bring in all of the columns with the rows, or just columns? When I change to cur.description(), I get the below error: line 93, in <module>
    query = cur.description()
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable.

Comment: Just columns without rows.

Answer (score 1):

With ebyhr's help response, I found another thread that guided me to the answer using Pandas.

```
conn = prestodb.dbapi.connect(
    host='hostname',
    port=4443,
    user='username',
    catalog='meld',
    schema='athena',
    http_scheme='https',
    auth=prestodb.auth.BasicAuthentication("username", "password"),
)

cur = conn.cursor()
query = cur.execute(""" SELECT * FROM meld.athena.athena_business_summary limit 10 """)
queryFetch = cur.fetchall()
queryResults = pd.DataFrame.from_records(queryFetch, columns = [i[0] for i in cur.description])
print(queryResults)
```

I am sure there is a more consolidated way to do it, but I hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use pandas [read_sql_query](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_sql_query.html).

In your case, it would be:

```py
conn = prestodb.dbapi.connect(
    host='hostname',
    port=4443,
    user='username',
    catalog='meld',
    schema='athena',
    http_scheme='https',
    auth=prestodb.auth.BasicAuthentication("username", "password"),
)

query = "SELECT * FROM meld.athena.athena_business_summary limit 10"
res = pd.read_sql_query(query, conn)
print(res)
```

It will give you a Dataframe with column names.

This also works well with Trino's `trino.dbapi.connect`.

Answer (score 0):

Adapting Scott's answer I done this which I find is more efficient

```py
def run_presto(query):
    with prestodb.dbapi.connect(
        host="some_host",
        port=8443,
        user="xxx",
        catalog="xxx",
        schema="xxx",
        http_scheme="https",
        auth=prestodb.auth.BasicAuthentication("xxx", "xxx"),
    ) as conn:
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute(query)

        return {"data": cur.fetchall(), "cols": cur.description}
```

Then generated a DataFrame like so

```py
data = run_presto(
"""
select * from some_table;
"""
)


df = pd.DataFrame(data['data'], columns=[i[0] for i in data['cols']])
```

Running Presto with as a context manager like here:

```py
with prestodb.dbapi.connect(...) as conn
```

Allows us to automatically close the connection, which is helpful in saving resources.